# Time.zone.now not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I have the following:

**config/application.rb**

```
config.time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

**controllers/time_trackers_controller.rb**

```
@track_it.clock_in = Time.zone.now
```

The time now in my time zone (Eastern Time) is supposed to be 13:02 but if I save it in the database it shows up as 17:02 and I don't understand why. Any tips on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Rails converts everything to UTC before it puts it in the database. So what you're seeing is totally normal, and when you pull the record back out of the database, the time zone will be Eastern.

Comment: I restarted my server. Now it saves it correctly in the database but the output is not correct. It is 4 hours earlier. I don't understand if it converts it to UTC then what did I do this time?

Comment: I had a similar thing happen once. You probably saved records under time zone A, but then changed your time zone to time zone B, and the time zone change took effect when you restarted your server. Now, when you get the records out of your database, they're correct with respect to time zone A, but not with respect to time zone B. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I would recommend that you set `config.time_zone` to Eastern, but not specify `config.active_record.default_timezone`. Then restart your server. Then blow away all your existing data. Then save some records and see what happens.